# How to compare key pressed with a stored array and then replace letters in another array

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, i know the title is confusing so here is the explanation.

1. This is a Homework assignment and i am completely stuck on this task.
2. I am creating a simple Hangman game and have gotten as far as having the computer pick a random word from a list (current code has the list set to 1 item while i was fixing a couple other bugs).

So here is what i am asking. At line 45 i am trying to compare the the letters stored in lettersGuessed with the value stored in randomWord. IF the value matches a letter in the randomWord array then print that to the HTML doc, if not then keep allowing the user to try untill they reach 0 tries remaining.
I have tried a a for loop with a nested if but the comparison never works.

I know i have to do some code clean up but first i want to get this working then refactor it.

Thanks in advance!

```js
//This will hold an list of words to guess in the game
var wordsToGuess = ["abc"];
//Global variables//
//variables to hold score count
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var guessesRemaining = 10;
//Empty arras to store letters guessed
var lettersGuessed = [];
//Empty arras to store the word to guess
var randomWord = [];
var word = [];


//When the enter key is pressed a new word is slected and the Current Word section is replaced with dashes
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    word = [];
    start();
  }
}, false);

//function to start and re-start the game when needed
function start() {

  //Randomizer to pick random a word from wordsToGuess array
  randomWord = wordsToGuess[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsToGuess.length)];
  console.log(randomWord);

  //This adds the dashes for the number of letters of the picked word
  for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
    word[i] = "_";
  }
  console.log(word);
  document.getElementById("current-word").innerHTML = word;


  //when the player presses a key well run some code
  document.onkeyup = function(event) {

    //To determine what key is pressed and save it to lettersGuessed
    lettersGuessed.push(event.key);

    //Print letters guessed to page
    document.getElementById("guessed-letters").innerHTML = lettersGuessed;
    console.log(lettersGuessed);
    //check if letter guessed is equal to any of the letters in the word
    if (randomWord.indexOf(lettersGuessed) === -1) {
        word.push(lettersGuessed);
    }else{
    guessesRemaining--;
    document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guessesRemaining;
    console.log(guessesRemaining);
    }
    /*
    guessesRemaining--;
    document.getElementById("guesses").innerHTML = guessesRemaining;
    console.log(guessesRemaining);
    */
  }
}

//each time the player guesses a correct letter
//current word should update

//each time the player wins

//each time the player loses
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Hangman-Game</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../assets/css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="../assets/Javascript/game.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="card mb-3">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="../assets/images/Star_Wars_Logo.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is my StarWars Hangman Game. Here are the rules...just guess letters and try to win. All words can come from any StarWars movie but will be limited to characters in the movies and Cartoon shows (not including books) Press ENTER to start.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        This column will hold my images
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        This side will hold by game
        <p class="wins">Wins:
          <span id="wins">0</span>
        </p>
        <p class="losses">Losses:
          <span id="losses">0</span>
        </p>
        <br/>
        <p>Current Word: </p>
        <p>
          <span id="current-word">""</span>
        </p>
        <p>Guessed Letters: </p>
        <p>
          <span id="guessed-letters">""</span>
        </p>
        <p>Guesses Remaining: </p>
        <p>
          <span id="guesses">10</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>





  <footer class="footer position-relative">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">Copyright Roberto Benites 2018</span>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!--BootStrap links-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Who will point out where the 45th line is. Better point it out in the comments

Comment: Sorry, yes looks like i removed that code.
Here is what it was:

if (randomWord.indexOf(lettersGuessed) === -1) {
            word.push(lettersGuessed);
        }else{

Comment: added the code back in. I removed it because it did not work.

Comment: I also tried this and it alerts correct for every input.

for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
            if (lettersGuessed[i] === randomWord[i]) {
                alert("correct");
            }
        }

Comment: Use console.log to see what values you are outputting in randomWord[i] and lettersGuessed[i].

Comment: Here. I did this for fun.  You still have to organize the letters and let the player know they won and update the pictures but it's the gist of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/bLstwekn/133/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the correct word in a var and loop through each character in it and then put each character from the correct word into a correct words array.When a user inputs a letter, You can loop through your correct word array and check if that letter is in the correct word array or not. If it is. Put it into an array of correct letters guessed. If it's not. Put it into an array of wrong letters guessed. Also remember that your letter that you guess could be in the correct word array multiple times. You also want to check if guesses remaining == 0 and also erase part of the hangman if the letter guessed is wrong. This basic logic though should separate your correct letters and your incorrect letters into two separate arrays which you will need to perform more logic on.  You'll also need to display the correct letters within the correct spots which shouldn't be too tricky. Good luck and I hope this helps.

```
var str = "correctWord"
var word = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
word.push(str.charAt(i));
}
for(var i =0; i< word.length; i++)
{
 if(i == guessedletter)
 {
   correctlettersGuessed.push(i);
 }
 else
 {
  wrongGuessedLetter.push(guessedletter);
 }
 guessesRemaining--; 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hie! Try this: [codepen](https://codepen.io/g1un/pen/WzQgqR?editors=1011)
Maybe not optimal but does work as needed.
HTML (just as yours except id='guesses' element and 'Press ENTER...' text):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Hangman-Game</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../assets/css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="../assets/Javascript/game.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="card mb-3">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="../assets/images/Star_Wars_Logo.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is my StarWars Hangman Game. Here are the rules...just guess letters and try to win. All words can come from any StarWars movie but will be limited to characters in the movies and Cartoon shows (not including books). <span id='status' style='color: red;'>Press ENTER to start!</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        This column will hold my images
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        This side will hold by game
        <p class="wins">Wins:
          <span id="wins">0</span>
        </p>
        <p class="losses">Losses:
          <span id="losses">0</span>
        </p>
        <br/>
        <p>Current Word: </p>
        <p>
          <span id="current-word">""</span>
        </p>
        <p>Guessed Letters: </p>
        <p>
          <span id="guessed-letters">""</span>
        </p>
        <p>Guesses Remaining: </p>
        <p>
          <span id="guesses">10</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>





  <footer class="footer position-relative">
    <div class="container">
      <span class="text-muted">Copyright Roberto Benites 2018</span>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!--BootStrap links-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is js code:

```
function Game() {
  //VARIABLES
  var _this = this;
  var wins = 0;
  var losses = 0;
  var wordsList = ['stars', 'wars'];
  var messages = {
    off: 'Press ENTER to start!',
    on: 'You are playing now!'
  };

  //init each game  
  var lettersGuessed;
  var guessesRemaining;
  var status;
  var wordToGuess;
  var resultWord;

  //DOM ELEMENTS
  var $gameStatus = document.getElementById("status");
  var $wins = document.getElementById("wins");
  var $losses = document.getElementById("losses");
  var $guessedLetters = document.getElementById("guessed-letters");
  var $leftGuessesCounter = document.getElementById("guesses");
  var $currentWord = document.getElementById("current-word");

  //INIT
  this.init = function() {
    setDefaults();

    //EVENTS
    window.addEventListener('keyup', begin);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', play);

    //to begin the game
    function begin(e) {
      if(e.keyCode === 13 && status === 'off') {
        status = 'on';
        render('status');
        render('resultWord');
        render('lettersGuessed');
        render('guessesRemaining');
      }
    }

    function play(e) {
      if(status === 'on') {
        start(e);
      }
    }
  };

  //SET DEFAULTS
  function setDefaults() {
    lettersGuessed = [];
    render('lettersGuessed');
    guessesRemaining = 10;
    render('guesses');
    status = 'off';
    render('status');
    wordToGuess = wordsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsList.length)];  
    //word with letters that player has found
    resultWord = new Array(wordToGuess.length + 1).join('_').split('');
  };

  //START
  function start(e) {
    if(status === 'on') {
      var code = e.keyCode
      //check if it is a char
      if(code > 64 && code < 91) {
        var char = e.key;
        //check if char was already named
        if(lettersGuessed.indexOf(char) === -1) { 
          lettersGuessed.push(char);
          render('lettersGuessed');
          //if char is in wordToGuess
          if(wordToGuess.indexOf(char) !== -1) {
            for(var i = 0; i<wordToGuess.length; i++) {
              if(wordToGuess[i] === char) resultWord[i] = char;
            }
            render('resultWord');
            //check if won
            if(wordToGuess === resultWord.join('')) {
              wins++;
              render('wins');
              alert('You\'ve won!');
              setDefaults();
            }
          } else {
            guessesRemaining--;
            render('guesses');
            if(guessesRemaining === 0) {
              losses++;
              render('losses');
              alert('You\'ve lost!');
              setDefaults();
            }
          }            
        } else {
          alert('You\'ve tried this character already!');
        }          
      } else {
        console.log('It\'s not a character!');
      }
    }
  };

  //RENDER
  function render(el) {
    switch(el) {
      case 'status':
        $gameStatus.innerText = messages[status];
        break;
      case 'resultWord':
        $currentWord.innerText = resultWord.join(' ');
        break;
      case 'guesses':
        $leftGuessesCounter.innerText = guessesRemaining;
        break;
      case 'lettersGuessed':
        $guessedLetters.innerText = lettersGuessed.join(',');
        break;
      case'wins':
        $wins.innerText = wins;
      case'losses':
        $losses.innerText = losses;
    }
  };
}; 

new Game().init();
```

Comment: awesome. this looks great. Unfortunately can't use jquery for this game :'(

Comment: @robert It is pure javascript! There is no jQuery. Names like "$gameStatus" are used just to see DOM elements varibles. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @robert Also this link <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script> is from your initial code and doesn't influence my one.

Comment: Thanks! Was not aware that the $ operator was used in JS as well.

Comment: @robert You are kidding! Or too new to js.) '$' is not an operator here. It is just a symbol like any other character or sign (a, b, c ...). In jQuery it is just an alias for 'jQuery' and uses with braces or with dot, e.g.: $('div'), $.each(), etc